# Don't apply tailwindcss to certain react components

Tags: reactjs, markdown, tailwind-css

is there a way to disable tailwindcss styles from being applied to certain react components? I am trying to use `react-markdown` which will convert a markdown file into JSX. However, since tailwindcss will disable the default styling of header tags (eg. the `<h1>` tag), the markdown does not display properly.

Is it possible to disable tailwind for the specific file that uses react-markdown to render the markdown file? Or is there another way to display markdown files in React using tailwind.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a [typography plugin for tailwind](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography). You could check it out too.

Here is a [link](https://tjaddison.com/blog/2020/08/updating-to-tailwind-typography-to-style-markdown-posts/) for setting up the typography plugin and applying it to only parts of a react app.